# Saving Object in SQLite Database, no exception - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, insert

I'm getting crazy right now with a problem, while saving an object in a SQLite database. I've got an UI in which you can insert some data in TextEdits and Checkboxes. 
This is the BaseListFragment, which handles the UI for different types:

```
    package de.financeplanner.ui.fragment;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.financeplanner.R;
import de.financeplanner.constant.TabConstants;
import de.financeplanner.model.Category;
import de.financeplanner.model.Finance;
import de.financeplanner.model.Model;
import de.financeplanner.util.adapter.list.CategoryListAdapter;
import de.financeplanner.util.adapter.list.FinanceListAdapter;
import de.financeplanner.util.db.DBHelperCategory;
import de.financeplanner.util.db.DBHelperFinance;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 20.01.2017.
 */

public class BaseListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private ArrayList<? extends Model> listData;
    private short type;

    public static BaseListFragment newInstance(short type){
        BaseListFragment fragment = new BaseListFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putShort("type", type);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        type = getArguments().getShort("type");
        listData = loadListData(type);
        initList();
        initAddButton();
        //   getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private ArrayList<? extends Model> loadListData(short type){
        switch (type) {
            case TabConstants.OVERVIEW:
                return loadFinances();
            case TabConstants.REVENUE:
                return loadRevenues();
            case TabConstants.EXPENSE:
                return loadExpenses();
            case TabConstants.CATEGORY:
                return loadCategories();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private ArrayList<Finance> loadFinances() {
        DBHelperFinance dbHelper = new DBHelperFinance(getContext());
        return dbHelper.getAll();
    }

    private ArrayList<Finance> loadRevenues() {
        DBHelperFinance dbHelper = new DBHelperFinance(getContext());
        return dbHelper.getRevenues();
    }

    private ArrayList<Finance> loadExpenses() {
        DBHelperFinance dbHelper = new DBHelperFinance(getContext());
        return dbHelper.getExpanse();
    }

    private ArrayList<Category> loadCategories() {
        DBHelperCategory dbHelper = new DBHelperCategory(getContext());
        return dbHelper.getAll();
    }



    private void initList() {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = null;
        if (listData != null) {
            if (type != TabConstants.CATEGORY) {
                adapter = new FinanceListAdapter(getContext(), (ArrayList<Finance>)listData);
            }else{
                adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(getContext(), (ArrayList<Category>)listData);
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private void initAddButton() {
        ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if(type != TabConstants.CATEGORY){
                    trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, AddFinanceFragment.newInstance());
                    trans.addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }else{
                    trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, AddCategoryFragment.newInstance());
                    trans.addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For explanation:
You cann choose 4 different tabs (overview, revenue, expense and category). The UI is every time the same, only the data inside changes.

Now, when I click on the `addButton` inside the category tab and insert data, the data is saved inside the database and the listview is correctly updated.
This is the called method to save the category.

```
 private void onSaveRequest(){
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setTitle(title.getText().toString());
    category.setDescription(description.getText().toString());
    DBHelperCategory dbHelper = new DBHelperCategory(getContext());
    dbHelper.saveOrUpdate(category);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

And this is the DBHelper method, which is called to save the category:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Category category){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", category.getTitle());
    values.put("description", category.getDescription());
    if(category.getId() == 0){
        save(values);
    } else {
        update(values);
    }
}

private void save(ContentValues values){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert("category", null, values);
}
```

This is the method, to get categories from the database:

```
public ArrayList<Category> getAll(){
    ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rows =  db.rawQuery(GET_ALL_QUERY, null);
    rows.moveToFirst();
    while(!rows.isAfterLast()){
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(rows.getInt(0));
        category.setTitle(rows.getString(1));
        category.setDescription(rows.getString(2));
        categories.add(category);
        rows.moveToNext();
    }

    return categories;
}
```

The problem is, when I click the `addButton` inside the overview, revenue or expense tab, no data is insert into database and the listview is not updated.
And this the method, which is called, when the `saveButton` is pressed:

```
private void onSaveRequest(){
    Finance finance = new Finance();
    finance.setTitle(title.getText().toString());
    finance.setCategoryID(0);
    finance.setDescription(description.getText().toString());
    finance.setPayment(Double.parseDouble(payment.getText().toString()));
    finance.setExpense(expense.isChecked());
    finance.setDate(date.getText().toString());
    DBHelperFinance dbHelper = new DBHelperFinance(getContext());
    dbHelper.saveOrUpdate(finance);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

And this is the method inside the DBHelper, which should insert the data in the database:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Finance finance){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", finance.getTitle());
    values.put("categoryID", finance.getCategoryID());
    values.put("description", finance.getDescription());
    values.put("payment", finance.getPayment());
    values.put("expense", finance.isExpense() ? 1 : 0);
    values.put("date", finance.getDate());
    if(finance.getId() == 0){
        save(values);
    } else {
        update(values);
    }
}

private void save(ContentValues values){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert("finance", null, values);
}
```

This are the methods, to get the finances from the database:

```
private ArrayList<Finance> getAll(short condition){
    ArrayList<Finance> finances = new ArrayList<Finance>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereClause = new String();
    final String join = " INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON FINANCE.categoryID = CATEGORY.ID ";
    if(condition != 0){
        whereClause = condition == 1 ? " WHERE EXPENSE = 0 " : "WHERE EXPENSE = 1";
    }
    String query = GET_ALL_QUERY + join + whereClause;
    Cursor rows =  db.rawQuery(query, null);
    rows.moveToFirst();
    while(!rows.isAfterLast()){
        Finance finance = new Finance();
        finance.setId(rows.getInt(0));
        finance.setTitle(rows.getString(1));
        finance.setCategoryID(rows.getInt(2));
        finance.setCategory(rows.getString(3));
        finance.setDescription(rows.getString(4));
        finance.setPayment(rows.getDouble(5));
        finance.setExpense(rows.getInt(6) == 1);
        finance.setDate(rows.getString(7));
        finances.add(finance);
        rows.moveToNext();
    }

    return finances;
}
```

To complete this, here is the super class for every DBHelper:

```
    package de.financeplanner.util.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 20.01.2017.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "financeDB";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE FINANCE " +
                "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TITLE VARCHAR(50), CATEGORYID INTEGER," +
                "DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(240), PAYMENT DECIMAL(8,2), EXPENSE BOOLEAN," +
                "DATE STRING); ");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CATEGORY " +
                "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TITLE VARCHAR(50), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(240));");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FINANCE");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CATEGORY");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

I've debugged the app and can't find anything wrong. (Just, that every ArrayList is empty, so nothing is insert into database). Even there is no exception or other error shown, so I think the Syntax and the fields for the database is also right. Strange is also, that in the morning everything worked and I really don't know, what I've changed that everything goes wrong right now.

Comment: In your finance table you have `CATEGORYID` but you reference it as `FINANCE.categoryID` along with your values, they are lowercase, yet the columns in your database are uppercase i.e. `values.put("title", finance.getTitle());` and your database column name `TITLE` also your insert method has the table as lowercase, but the tables are uppercase. Make all the columns/names static variables and reference them from that.

Comment: I saw, that there is a problem with the INNER JOIN in the sql statement. The categoryID wasn't the same as the category.id. This problem occured, because I've get the position from the spinner and not the id of the object inside the spinner....shame on me!